# xpath / xslt: find the last node depending on the sub nodes

Tags: xslt, xpath

How can I find the last node that contains a specific structure?

```
    <defect-event>
        <event-assigned-to>
            <assigned-to-user>
                <last-name>Doe</last-name>
                <first-name>John</first-name>
                <middle-name></middle-name>
            </assigned-to-user>
        </event-assigned-to>
    </defect-event>
```

There can be many "defect-event" nodes at the same level, below or above the one with the "assigned-to-user" sub node.
There can also be multiple "defect-event" nodes with the "assigned-to-user" sub node.

I need to find the last one "defect-event" node which contains the "assigned-to-user" sub node.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something on these lines is probably what you want:

```
defect-event[event-assigned-to[assigned-to-user]][position()=last()]
```

In effect, you're saying "find me all the `defect-event` which contains an `event-assigned-to` containing an `assigned-to-user`, and then just give me the one whose `position()` is `last()`".

Having said that, you might need to tweak this depending on the context you're in when you try to find the node, and what you're doing to the node (eg: behaviour might vary if you're in a `for-each` loop as opposed to an `apply-templates` situation).

Comment: Thanks for the description Emma, it works but I can't find how to get the nodes values now, for example `last-name`
`<xsl:variable name="lastName" select="defect-event[event-assigned-to[assigned-to-user]][position()=last()]"/>` and then `<xsl:value-of select="$lastName/last-name"/>`; do you know what I should change?

Comment: I just found out:
`<xsl:variable name="lastName" select="defect-event[event-assigned-to[assigned-to-user]][position()=last()]/event-assigned-to/assigned-to-user/last-name"/>`
Thanks!

Comment: @user706058 Glad to know it helped and you worked out that my suggestion gives you the `defect-event` element, so you can just navigate down its children to get the desired information.